# A functor between $S \rightarrow S_*$ (of quasicategories)

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

On [p.60 of Moritz Groth short course on $\infty$-category](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.2925.pdf) he writes, 
If $C$ is an $\infty$-category adding a disjoint base point defines a functor 
$$_+:C \rightarrow C_{*/}$$
where $C_{*/}$ is the slice category over $*$.  How is this defined?

Thoughts: I know a morphism $* : \Delta^0 \rightarrow C$ determines a distinct point on each level $C_n$. By adjunction, defining a map $C \rightarrow C_*$ is equivalent to a morphism 
$$\Delta^0 \star C \rightarrow C $$ 
The natural map seems to be collapse on each level $n$ everything else other than $C_n$, which we take to be identity.

Comment: Have you looked at the first chapter of Luries "Higher Algebra"?

Comment: He refers to 7.2.2.1 of HTT. Which I find more complicated then the construction here. But I would really like to hear how one shows those two defs are equivalent.

Comment: In 7.2.2.1 the notion of pointed objects is defined. For the equivalence with how Moritz Groth defined this, see HTT. 7.2.2.8. As for your question, if $\mathcal C$ has finite coproducts then the functor you want is simply the cobase change along $\emptyset\to \ast$. Formally the functor can be defined by using the theory of Cartesian and Cocartesian fibrations, see HTT, 6.1.1 for a discussion of the dual notion of base change.

Comment: Cool, I should look into this, would you want to C&P this as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTT, 7.2.2.1 the notion of pointed objects is defined. For the equivalence with how Moritz Groth defined this, see HTT, 7.2.2.8. As for your question, if $C$ has finite coproducts then the functor you want is simply the cobase change along $\emptyset \to \ast$. Formally the functor can be defined by using the theory of Cartesian and Cocartesian fibrations, see HTT, 6.1.1 for a discussion of the dual notion of base change and apply this to $C^{\mathrm{op}}$ to obtain the result that you are after.